# recover problem: file format not supported error

Tags: c, cs50, recover

I'm trying to solve this problem which consists of reading data from a "memory card" and write it into new readable jpg files.

I'm getting 50 files named correctly as far as I can tell but their data is incorrect. to me it looks like it should be writing into each jpg the data read into the buffer from the card or argv[1] but I'm guessing I'm missing something and I can't figure out what.
this is what I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int is_jpg(BYTE(buffer[]))
{
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xe0) == 0xe0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BYTE buffer[512];

    //checks argument validity
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //printf("continuing program\n");

    //checks if the file exists
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("No file found\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int file_count = 0;
    char file_name[8];
    //sprintf(file_name,  "%03d.jpg", file_count);
    FILE *image;

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        if (is_jpg(buffer) == 1)
        {
            if (file_count != 0)
            {
                fclose(image);
            }
            sprintf(file_name,  "%03d.jpg", file_count);
            image = fopen(file_name, "w");
            fread(&buffer, 512, 1 , file);
            fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, image);
            file_count++;
        }
        else if (file_count > 0)
        {
               fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, image);
        }
        //fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you detect the header, you do an *extra* `fread` [after the `image = fopen(file_name, "w");` call].

You want to write the header to the output file/stream. But, the extra `fread` trashes the header data and the first block of the file is data and *not* the header as you desire.

You *only* want the `fread` at the top of the loop.